# How to generate xml tag for value

Tags: sql-server, xml

I wish to generate xml data in the following format - animal value must be tag name

```
<pets>
  <dog>
    <name>spot</name>
  </dog>
  <cat>
    <name>tom</name>
  </cat>
</pets>
```

I can write some dynamic sql but if there is a better way????

```
;with cte(animal,name)
as
(
    select 'dog','spot' union
    select 'cat','tom'
)
select 
    animal
    ,name
from cte
for xml path(animal),root('pets')
```

Comment: If the values are know (e.g. dogs and cats always) you could do a pivot to get the column names 'dog' and 'cat'. Other than that, you could do something like `cast('<' + animal + '>' + name + '</' + animal + '>' as xml)`

Comment: Thanks - ;with cte(animal,name)
as
(
 select 'dog','spot' union
 select 'cat','tom'
)
select 
 cast('<'+animal+'>' + '<name>'+name+'</name>' + '</'+animal+'>' as xml)
from cte
for xml path(''),root('pets')

Answer (score 1):

Use the next code:-

```
SELECT ( 
SELECT 'spot' AS name
FOR
XML PATH('dog'),
TYPE
),
( SELECT 'tom' AS name
FOR
XML PATH('cat'),
TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH(''),
ROOT('Pets')
GO
```

**Result:-**

```
<Pets>
  <dog>
    <name>spot</name>
  </dog>
  <cat>
    <name>tom</name>
  </cat>
</Pets>
```

Comment: That is great if it was just two records.  I could loop through each record and dynamically create each row but that seems rather naff.  Any more suggestions?